# Javascript - SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript

When I try to make `<div id="test">this should go down</div>` go down with:

```
<div onclick="(".test").slideDown(800);">close it</div>
```

I get this error everytime i click 'close it'

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Please let me know, what I'm doing wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Are you using jQuery? I'm guessing you are by the syntax.

Comment: Just as a note, I'm assuming you're writing this in Notepad, as virtually everything else offers syntax highlighting. With this, you should _immediately_ notice something weird within your quotes using something like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [vim](http://www.vim.org/) or even the Stack Overflow interface. I'd definitely recommend switching.

Comment: THank you everyone, with your help I got it to work <3

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
<div onclick="$('.test').slideDown(800);">close it</div>
```

or even better as it seems that you are using jquery:

```
<div id="close">close it</div>
```

and in a separate javascript file:

```
$('#close').click(function() {
    $('.test').slideDown(800);
});
```

See how cleaner this is? You no longer need to mix markup with javascript and have problems as the one you are encountering currently.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting explaining why you think this answer is wrong.

Comment: @andyb, why `.test` should be `#test`? It could be a class selector, couldn't it?

Comment: It could be but the question has `<div id="test">`

Answer (score 2):

Change on of the uses of double quotes (and I'm guessing you're using jQuery so you'll also need to add the $ shortcut (or full jQuery call):

```
onclick="$('.test').slideDown(800);"

// or

onclick='$(".test").slideDown(800);'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an ID selector for the `<div id="test">` but trying to use a class selector to animate the `<div>` with `$(.test`) which will never match. However your code is also has bad quotes which is causing the SyntaxError, so to fix everything one of the following should help :-)

HTML:

```
<div id="closeIt">close it</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#closeIt').click(function() {
    $('#test').slideDown(800);
});
```

or Complete example (with separate bound function):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#closeIt').click(function() {
                $('#test').slideDown(800);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #test {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div id="closeIt">close it</div>
<div id="test">this should go down</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

or inline onclick (not recommended as this doesn't separate markup from behaviour but it still works)

```
<div onclick="$('#test').slideDown(800);">close it</div>
```